# What is the use of this line in collection of objects

Tags: java

```
ListIterator litr = al.listIterator();
```

What is the use of above line doing and is ListIterator object created? Please explain the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`al` is the name of a reference that points to a `List` object on the heap.

The `List` class has a method `listIterator` that returns a reference to a `ListIterator` object.  It allows you to walk through the elements in the `al` `List`.

You cannot be a Java developer without being able to read and understand [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

[Here](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/06/listiterator-in-java-with-examples/) are some examples.

Comment: Thanks for the response